# JPA OnetoMany relationship

Tags: jpa, one-to-many

I have 3 entity classes mapped below:

```java
@Table(name = "PROVIDER")
public class Provider implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private long npi;
    private String name;
    private String specialization;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "provider", cascade = REMOVE)
    @OrderBy
    private List<Treatment> treatments;
    @Transient
    private ITreatmentDAO treatmentDAO;
    // and so forth
}

@Table(name = "PATIENT")
public class Patient implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private long patientid;
    private String name;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthDate;
    @OneToMany(cascade = REMOVE, mappedBy = "patient")
    @OrderBy
    private List<Treatment> treatments;
    // and so forth
}

@Table(name = "TREATMENT")
public abstract class Treatment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    private String diagnosis;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Patient patient;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_fk", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Provider provider;
    // and so forth
}
```

When I invoke getTreatments on either Patient or Provider, I expect JPA to fill in the treatments attribute. However this only works for Provider. No matter what I try, patient.getTreatments() always returns empty.

What am I missing?

Here is the Unit test on the server end:

```
@Test
public void TestAddTreatment() throws PatientExn, ProviderExn {
        GregorianCalendar bd = new GregorianCalendar();
        bd.set(1977, 03, 13);
    Patient patient = this.pf.createPatient(900L, "Orezi.Dauda", bd.getTime());
    Provider provider = this.prf.createProvider(6777L, "Sam.OKafor");
    this.pdao.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    this.pdao.addPatient(patient);
    this.pdao.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    this.prdao.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
    this.prdao.addProvider(provider);
    provider.addDrugTreatment(900L, "Malaria", "Chloroquine", (float)5.0);
    this.prdao.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
    List<Long> providerTids = this.prdao.getProviderByNpi(6777L).getTreatmentIds();
    List<Long>patientTids = this.pdao.getPatientByPatientId(900L).getTreatmentIds();
    assert(providerTids.size() == 1); //Passes
    assert(patientTids.size() == 1);// Fails
}
```

Comment: wow... How do you check than the list is empty, debugger ? Do you see the sql query triggered by the lazy load operation ? Are you sure you have effective commited data in database ?

Comment: Yup. I see the entries in the database with patient_fk and provider_fk for the treatment record. When I get the treatments when i do provider.getTreatments but not for the patient no matter what i do. Was thinking I missed something trivial...

Comment: probably... but I'am missing it too ;) As it is lazy provider.getTreatments() will remains empty until you call a method on the list like getSize() or get(0) for example.

Comment: please post the code you use to test

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line `@OneToMany(cascade = REMOVE, mappedBy = "patient")` with

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "patient", orphanRemoval = true) and try it should work
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I did make the suggested changes but still no luck?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure when you create/update your objects you are adding to both sides of the relationship.

Comment: Provider calls a add operation like so:

Comment: Provider service creates both Patient and Provider instances and invokes addTreatment on both. 
When I later do a getTreatments on both instances I only get treatments for provider. This is the weird problem. I will post the code when I get home tonight. Thanks, Sam

Comment: It actually does. The line:
provider.addDrugTreatment(900L, "Malaria", "Chloroquine", (float)5.0);

Takes the patientID (900L), gets the patient with that id from the db and does patient.addTreatment() on it